# Doing RAID 1 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ssd, raid, raid-1

After doing some research about RAID options and benefits I'm thinking (or shall I say - curious) of doing RAID on my two SSDs. In Disk Utility it allows me to do "Mirrored RAID set" (RAID 1?), "Stripped RAID set" (RAID 0?) and "Concatenated Disk Set" (what is that?).

My choice is to do a mirrored RAID set and have my two SSDs copies of each other. It should be slower in terms of writing performance since writing speed = min(disk1,disk2) but theoretically the reading speed should be faster since the information is contained in both disks. Does the Mac Pro hardware (and/or OS X) has the capability to take advantage of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenated RAID is usually for more than two disks to have a kind of JBOD setup however for your two SSD's I would focus as your mentioned on 0 or 1.

You mentioned RAID 1 is the preferable route due to redundancy.

Firstly in answer to your question yes write will be slower however SSD's will you notice it probably not.

Secondly read has the potential to be faster however that is fully down to how well the Disk Utility handles the RAID. For example a full enterprise Server with hardware raid for RAID 1 you will most likely see a read increase as its a very clever dedicated RAID controller, for Mac OS X its up for debate I've never tested the speeds myself. One thing for sure is that it will not be slower.

Now one thing to consider moving on from this is that this setup is a software RAID not hardware which means that Mac OS X is controlling the RAID not the underlying hardware. What this means for you is that you will need to get in to OS X to rebuild the RAID array should a hard drive fail. If the hard drive failure causes OS X to not boot then chances are you will not be able to recover that RAID set like you could at hardware level.

Hope this clears things up a little happy to help more just comment any questions you have.